# How to add a Security Group to AD using LDAP and php

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm brand new to pretty much all of this - ldap, php, active directory. I'm expanding some code written by someone else that's long gone, so the usual...

I'm pretty sure I need to use ldap_add:

```
bool ldap_add ( resource $link_identifier , string $dn , array $entry )
```

but I'm confused mostly - I think - about how to build the dn. Could someone point me to some place to learn this or walk me through an example?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I was also all new in this, took me a long time to find out how ldap exactly works.

As you wrote correctly, the syntax of ldap_add is

```
bool ldap_add ( resource $link_identifier , string $dn , array $entry )
```

An very simplied example code for this:

```
$server = 'example.com';
$ds = ldap_connect($server);
$dn = 'cn=users,dc=example,dc=com';
$add['uid'] = 'ramon.johannessen'
$add["email"] = 'your@email.com';
ldap_add($ds, $dn, $add;
```

Don't forget to set the LDAP options before modifying entries:

```
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
```

And most servers require binding (I assume you're already doing this).

So put that before ldap_add()

**Edit:** to add a new folder inside cn=users

First, declare the DN in which the new group should be placed

```
$dn = 'cn=users,dc=example,dc=com';
```

Now, describe the desired attributes for this group. Depending on your LDAP server there are different requirements, but let's try this:

```
$add['objectclass'] = 'organizationalRole'; #this is a required attribute for a group
$add['cn'] = 'NewGroup'; #give any name
if(ldap_add($ds, $dn, $add)) echo "group ".$add['cn']." successfully added to ".$dn;
```

I'm just doing this off the cuff, hopes this helps you to create the new folder!

Comment: Thanks for going through this. What you've explained all makes sense, but I'm still a bit fuzzy though on adding a security group. How does the $dn string get built in that case?

Comment: You're welcome. Could you explain what you mean with adding a security group? If you narrow down your question to your specific situation, maybe I can help you with that.

Comment: Cool. So in AD, under Users, we have a bunch of objects in the list, different from the User type. These are of type Security Group, either Security Group - Global or Security Group - Universal. In the past they've been created in the AD GUI by right-clicking "Users" and selecting "New->Group". I want to be able to do this through a web page instead of being logged into the server. Does that make sense? Thanks again!

Comment: Sure this makes sense. I edited my answer to incorporate a solution.

Comment: I got side-tracked on some other stuff for a bit, going to get back to it soon-ish though.